# Is restriction to an open subset is a full functor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be an affine scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ a quasi-coherent sheaf. Then for any inclusion $j:U\hookrightarrow X$ for an open $U$, is the natural map $$\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F})\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F}|_U,\mathcal{F}|_U)$$
surjective?

Intuitively, it feels so, but I'm worried that this may fail possibly as you have to be careful when extending a morphism of sheaves...

If this is true, is it also true in more generality, that is for a ringed space and any sheaf of Abelian groups?

---

**CONEXT**

This popped up while I was trying to show that

> The natural morphism (given by the adjointness) $$\mathcal{F}\rightarrow j_{\ast}(\mathcal{F}|_U)$$  is a monomorphism of sheaves.

**EDIT**
I had made a mistake in my context: it should rather be

> $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow j_\ast j^\ast\mathcal{F}$ is injective iff $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F})\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F},j_\ast j^\ast\mathcal{F})$ is injective

This is true iff $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F})\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(j^\ast\mathcal{F}, j^\ast\mathcal{F})$ is injective by adjointness.

So the claim I would rather what to prove is, with the assumptions above,

> Is the natural map $$\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F})\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F}|_U,\mathcal{F}|_U)$$ injective?

Again this feels like its bound to fail with a good enough counter-example.

---

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original answer, before question was changed: No, this is very badly not true. Here's one simple example: consider $\mathcal{O}_X$. As $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F})\cong\mathcal{F}(X)$ for any $\mathcal{F}$, we find that $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong\mathcal{O}_X(X)$, while $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_X|_U,\mathcal{O}_X|_U)\cong\mathcal{O}_X(U)$. So if your claim was correct, $\mathcal{O}_X(X)\to\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ would always be a surjection for any open $U$. On the other hand, consider $D(t)\subset X=\operatorname{Spec} k[t]$, where $\mathcal{O}_X(X)=k[t]$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(D(t))=k[t,t^{-1}]$, and there's no surjection here.

---

After the question was changed: let me get straight to the point with your underlying question. Here is a counterexample:

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[t]$, let $\mathcal{F}=\widetilde{k[t]/(t)}$, and let $U=D(t)$. Then $j^*\mathcal{F}$ is the sheaf associated to the $k[t,t^{-1}]$-module $k[t]/(t)\otimes_{k[t]} k[t,t^{-1}]$, which is zero, so $j^*\mathcal{F}\cong 0$. Thus $\mathcal{F}\to j_*j^*\mathcal{F}$ is the zero map but $\mathcal{F}$ is not the zero sheaf, and so this map is not a monomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, this makes complete sense... precisely why I was a bit worried... would this mean the claim in the context is not true then?

Comment: Consider $\mathcal{F}=\widetilde{k[t]/(t)}$ on $\operatorname{Spec} k[t]$, and let $U=D(t)$. Then $j^*\mathcal{F}\cong \widetilde{k[t]/(t)\otimes_{k[t]} k[t,t^{-1}]} =0$, so $j_*j^*\mathcal{F}=0$ and $\mathcal{F}\to j_*j^*\mathcal{F}$ is the zero map and not a monomorphism. What lead you to this problem?

Comment: @PCeltide I've added the counterexample from the comments to the answer - your motivating question has a negative answer. Again, what lead you to this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Yes, that's a lovely example, thank you! I encountered this in a proof presented in my lectures on Serre's Criterion. In it, we say we have an exact sequence $0\to\mathcal{F}\to\bigoplus_{i=1}^n (j_i)_*\mathcal{F}|_{D(a_i)}\to\mathcal{G}\to 0$, with $\mathcal{G}$ is the cokernel and $(a_1,\dots,a_n)=A$, where $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$. It seems there may be an error...

Comment: That's a different problem entirely! I'd recommend writing a new post and referring back to this one to show some of your previous work.

Comment: Ah! So with the direct sum does the problem we were occurring earlier resolve? Of course, I will make a new post if required, but I would also like to just know where I erred in my reasoning to prove this claim instead.

Comment: Yes, the direct sum fixes it. The point of the counterexample is that you can "hide" something supported on $X\setminus U$ when dealing with one $F\to j_*j^*F$, while the direct sum uses an open cover which "sees everything" - given a point $x$, check what happens with $F\to j_*j^*F$ in the stalk at $x$ when $x\in U$, and then realize that since you have an open cover...

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you, I will attempt to go at this for a little bit and enquire about it with a reference to this post if needed, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hope this reasoning is well-enough: if $x\in U$, then we have an isomorphism $(j_*\mathcal{F}|_{U})_x\cong \varinjlim_{x\in V\subseteq X}\mathcal{F}|_{U}(U\cap V)\cong \varinjlim_{x\in V\subseteq U}\mathcal{F}|_U(V)\cong (\mathcal{F}|_U)_x\cong \mathcal{F}_x$... as our morphism $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow j_*\mathcal{F}|_U$ is natural, the morphism at stalks for $x\in U$ is the identity. Since we have an open cover, the image of a non-zero germ in under the stalks of the map $\mathcal{F}\to\bigoplus j_*\mathcal{F}|_{D(a_i)}$ will have at least one non-zero component.

Comment: That's basically correct, but your justification that the map on stalks is the identity feels a little handwavy to me (i.e. if you were a student and I was grading it, I would probably break out my red pen). One more concrete option is computing from the definition of the adjunction.